# Java native implementation to handling Modular Crypt Format

Tags: java, jce, pbkdf2

In my Java application, I am using PBKDF2-SHA256 in JCE for password hashing, and store the output of PBKDF2-SHA256 to the database directly.
Now I am trying to store the name of hashing algorithm and the time to stretch along with the hash value, for future enhancements.

To store these parameters, I think [Modular Crypt Format](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html) or [PHC String Format](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md) is suitable my purpose.
And in Python, you can handle Modular Crypt Format string by using Passlib.

### Question

Is there any native Java library to handle Modular Crypt Format or PHC String Format, to store hash value from JCE?
(Open source implementation is the best, but proprietary implementations are acceptable)

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I moved question to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47249/java-native-implementation-to-handling-modular-crypt-format